Aeolus Organ Not Starting Under UbStudio 24.10
Hi from Coastal Virginia USA. Running Ubuntu Studio 24.10 on a plain vanilla Dell Optiplex 760 dual-core PC, 2 GB RAM and a  Presonus Audiobox 22VSL interface.
When I try to start the Aeolus organ emulator, it opens and scans the first four or five stops, then crashes. The crash log is populated with 15MB of text characters, which I will spare you here. The only thing that looks familiar is SIGABRT on Line 413.
So why the crash, and how do I get around it? What should I be trying an where should I be looking?  Thanks one and all for the help.

First you should take a look at the system requirements which can be found here.

Who knows why it crashes. Water is wet, sky is blue, software can be buggy. I think contacting the developers is the best bet here.

This question is similar to: How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
